# Filter pipe throwing errors for table data

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I am trying to implement a search pipe for a data set with mixed values of string, number and boolean. I am trying to implement the following pipe 
[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/jXfqfCuJpKdw9HtL569T?p=preview), The link works great with a dataset with strings but I keep getting the error that toUpperCase() is not a function because it is unable to iterate through the data with different data types, please suggest me a way around. I have tried modifying the link in many ways but I am failing.
My Data set is as follows`{
            "pnr_id": 5037295,
            "uniqueId": 103739,
            "amount_paid": 37.2484,
            "name": "Sharon",
            "surname": "Monroe",
            "fullname": "Rhonda McLean",
            "email": "annette@puckett.mt",
            "amount_due": true,
            "amount_pending": 13.258,
            "user_name": "brandon@hanna.gf"
        },
        {
            "pnr_id": 5037296,
            "uniqueId": 195415,
            "amount_paid": 42.7672,
            "name": "Don",
            "surname": "Goldstein",
            "fullname": "Christina Carroll",
            "email": "steve@cochran.mo",
            "amount_due": true,
            "amount_pending": 35.9709,
            "user_name": "renee@rogers.ao"
        }`
Thank you and regards

working Plunkr link for data set with Strings:--
  https://plnkr.co/edit/jXfqfCuJpKdw9HtL569T?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you posted, `toUppercase` is a prototype function for `string`, when you call it directly from type out of string, this error will happen.

you can use `toString()` to convert `number`/`decimal` to `string`.

see the working **[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/IJiHumc1rGU1kxRpBNAE?p=preview)**.